# Report Builder Mysql field with multiple values querie empty

Tags: mysql, csv, reporting-services, parameters, where-clause

I'm trying to user Report Buider with a MySql code using a field with multiple values
my querie return empty.
If I type one value my querie works.

Querie:

```
SELECT field1,...
  FROM table1
  JOIN tbl2..
 WHERE ...
   AND Field1 IN (?)
```

And the  DataSet parameter ( ? ) is:
I tried  ("testx >" is to point the tentative, isn't the code):

```
test1 >   =Join(Parameters!param1.Value,",")
test2 >   =Join(Parameters!param1.Value,"','")
test3 >   =Split(Join(Parameters!param1.Value,","),",")    
test4 >   ="'" & Join(Parameters!param1.Value,"','") & "'"  
test5 >   =CStr(Join(Parameters!param1.Value,","))
test6 >   ="'" & CStr(Join(Parameters!param1.Value,",")) & "'" 
test7 >   =SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!param1.Value,","),",")
test8>   ="'" & Join(Parameters!param1.Value,"','") & "'"
```

If I use a parameter with only sinle vales and fill with,
for exemple:

```
'value1', 'value2' 
or
value1, value2
```

I have the same problem.

Does Anyone knows an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder (`?`) is passing the parameter as a literal string, not as a list. So your condition becomes:

```
AND Field1 IN ('value1, value2')
```

Which, obviously, does not do what you want (unless a single value is given).

Your best pick would be to split the string on application-side, and generate the correct number of placeholders. If that's not possible, then one workaround uses `find_in_set`:

```
AND find_in_set(Field1, replace(?, ', ', ','))
```

`replace()` is on purpose, because your csv string seems to have a space after each commas.

Comment: Some points, I;m using the formula: ="'" & Join(Parameters!param1.Value,"','") & "'" and if I print this value in some place of my report I see, for exemplo the string: 'xpto','xpto2'. This is what I need and what I'm passing in my query but doesn't work. I dont have application side, Im using SQL reporting service web plataform to render my reports.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after move the entire querie to a expression [exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeHdu.png)
Inside the expression I could use the parameter name instead of ? and I could format the parameters concateneds in the querie as I wish.

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeHdu.png)